# Why has Firefox dropped support for the HTML5 <keygen> tag?

Tags: html, firefox, cryptography, debian

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/keygen the HTML5 tag `<keygen>` is declared obsolete by the Mozilla developers.  The internet browser Firefox used to have  supported this until and up to version 69.0.3

Does anyone know why this was considered obsolete and how a similar functionality could be achieved?

Example use of `<keygen>` is the [Debian Single Signon procedure](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianSingleSignOn#SSO-enabled_sites)

Comment: I spend some more time researching and found this discussion thread: https://github.com/w3c/html/issues/43

Comment: I don't think it was ever supported in other browsers, and has been rendered obsolete by the numerous changes in the browser ecosystem since then, including the webcrypto API and many third-party Javascript crypto packages. Also, at one time client certificates were considered the future of client authentication, and <keygen> makes sense as a client-side key generation feature. Alas, it turned out the passwords were the future of client authentication as well as the past. Never bet against passwords.